# jhipster register page missing with okta

Tags: oauth, jhipster, okta

With Jhipster(5.0.0-beta.0) + Oauth + Okta, there is no registration page, only sign in page.

[image]

Can new users register somehow or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal, users need to register in Okta first. <strike>You can add a link to your Okta registration page yourself though</strike>.

EDIT:
As you pointed out, Okta has no self registration page, you must use the Okta's API to create the registration page yourself.

Comment: https://support.okta.com/help/answers?id=9062A000000bm6qQAA
There is no self registration page in Okta.

Comment: There's no built in registration page, you'll have to do it yourself then.

Comment: You can open a feature request on jhipster gihub project.

Comment: Where can I open feature request? Is the "New Issue" button is the correct way?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just follow the template when you create the ticket.

Comment: [Self-Service Registration feature](https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Directory/Directory_Self_Service_Registration.htm) is coming soon to okta.